# Fixing EF code generated from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-generation, t4

I am using the EF toolkit to create my POCO classes from an existing database. As the project proceeds I will have to generate this classes several times. The generated classes have some problems I do not want to have to correct every time  generate the code.

Problem 1:

It does not generate good property names when a table has tow foreign keys to the same table. Example:

It generates:

```
public partial class Flow
    {
        public virtual Element Element { get; set; }
        public virtual Element Element1 { get; set; }
    }
```

when I wanted:

```
public partial class Flow
    {
        public virtual Element FromElement { get; set; }
        public virtual Element ToElement { get; set; }
    }
```

This I solved by using partial classes like that:

```
public partial class Flow
{
    public virtual Element FromElement 
    {
        get {return Element;}
        set { Element = value; }
    }
    public virtual Element ToElement 
    {
        get {return Element1;}
        set {Element1=value;}
    }
}
```

This way I do not have to edit the generated classes.

Second Problem:

it does not recognize auto increment GUID properties on the database. It generates:

```
 public partial class Process
     {
         public System.Guid ProcessId { get; set; }
     }
```

When it should generate:

```
public partial class Process
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public System.Guid ProcessId { get; set; }
    }
```

Question is, How to I tell EF that these columns are autoincrement without having to insert
"[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]" before each primary key field on the generated classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found out it's easy to corect the T4 templates for the generated code. Just edit Mapping.tt and inserted the last line in the code below.:

```
// Primary Key
<#
    if (efHost.EntityType.KeyMembers.Count() == 1)
    {
#>
            this.HasKey(t => t.<#= efHost.EntityType.KeyMembers.Single().Name #>)
            .Property(t => t.<#= efHost.EntityType.KeyMembers.Single().Name #>).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```